# Internet Connection Monitor (free)

Tags: internet, adsl

I recently moved into a new house, that has telephone ADSL, every now and again it goes down. I wonder if there is some software (free) you can get that plays some alarm when the internet goes down. This way I can know when its down if I am in another room.

Comment: tip: check your router settings. change the connection from 'on demand' to 'nailed up' or 'always on'.

Comment: Thanks Molly, that's an extremely useful bit of information. When I get home, I will check it and post if it was the reason for the problem.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you can't connect work enough?  I'm trying to figure out why you need a sound every time it goes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a program ping regularly a well-known website that is known to be always available (google.com for instance) and alert you if it is not reachable.

[FreeMeter](http://www.tiler.com/freemeter/) has, amongst a [lot of features](http://www.tiler.com/freemeter/features/), this [functionnality](http://www.tiler.com/freemeter/features/alerts.php#PingMeter).

I think many other programs can do this.